Loss function for training a transformer language model
When training a language model, I would expect a maximum likelihood setting, i.e. searching for the model parameters that maximize the probability that the model generates the training text. Or equivalently, minimize -ln of that probability.
However the minimized loss function in Karpathy's Nano GPT seems slightly different, estimate_loss line 216. He also talks about this loss in this video, at minute 40.
If I understand correctly, his estimate_loss computes -ln of the probability to generate a substring, of same length as the context (i.e. the number of past words used to infer the next word), drawn at a random position in the training text. And estimate_loss does that multiple times and averages, so it is a Monte Carlo estimation of this global average:
(1 / training text length) * sum_{k < training text length} (-ln P (substring at k))

The constant denominator does not affect the minimization, so Karpathy's loss is equivalent to
sum_{k < training text length} (-ln P (substring at k))

Now the probability P (substring at k) is the product of the probabilities to generate each word in the substring, given the previous words in the substring, and the ln converts that into a sum, so we see that Karpathy's loss is actually a double sum. The number of terms in it is training text length * context length. This number is so high that Karpathy cannot fully compute this loss, which is probably why he just Monte Carlo estimates it in estimate_loss.
If we reorder the double sum, we do see the probability to generate the whole training text, as I was expecting: only take terms with full context. But in addition to those terms, the double sum also includes all subtrings with truncated contexts, of all sizes down to 1.
Is there a theoretical justification to use this alternative loss function, of which the vast majority of samples (truncated contexts) are not used during inference (generated texts always use full contexts, to have more information)?
